# How to do a 'join' lookup using Spring Data MongoDB 1.8.2?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I need to do a "join" between two different tables, my query is this:

```
db.Summary.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
           from: "OriginFilter",
           localField: "origin",
           foreignField: "code",
           as: "originObject"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "hub": 1,
            "moment": 1,
            "origin": { $arrayElemAt: [ "$originObject.displayName", 0 ] },
            "_id": 0
        }
    }
]);
```

And work perfectly, but I have no idea how I can do it in code using java with spring.

I have the LookupAggregationOperation class:

```
public class LookupAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private final DBObject operation;

    public LookupAggregationOperation(String from, String localField,
                                      String foreignField, String as) {
        
        this.operation = new BasicDBObject("$lookup",
                new BasicDBObject("from", from)
                        .append("localField", localField)
                        .append("foreignField", foreignField)
                        .append("as", as));
    }

    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return context.getMappedObject(operation);
    }
```

and I'm using it this way:

```
LookupAggregationOperation getOriginDisplayName = new LookupAggregationOperation("OriginFilter","origin","code","originObject");
```

then, I have a groupOperation:

```
GroupOperation groupByDay = group("moment.year", "moment.month", "moment.day", "moment.hour", "countType", "origin", "originObject")
                .sum("$count").as("count");
```

and finally I have a ProjectOperation:

```
ProjectionOperation renameFields = project("count", "countType")
                .and("_id.originObject.displayName").as("originDisplayName").and("_id.year").as("moment.year")
                .and("_id.month").as("moment.month")
                .and("_id.day").as("moment.day")
                .and("_id.hour").as("moment.hour");
```

but `and("_id.originObject.displayName").as("originDisplayName")` isnt working. How can I do the query above?

Comment: Huh? Spring 1.8.2? I don't think that version ever _existed_, and we're now up to **5.3**.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say Spring Data MongoDB 1.8.2. I just changed the title

Comment: You are having an issue with which stage of the aggregation? You have code for lookup, group and project stages using Spring-Data and Java (but, only lookup and project with the shell aggregation).